# How to describe a modulo operation in spoken words

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Several of the basic arithmetic operations can be described in spoken words such as:

- $x + y$ - Add $y$ to $x$
- $x - y$ - Subtract $y$ from $x$
- $x \times y$ - Multiply $x$ by $y$
- $x \div y$ - Divide $x$ by $y$

I'm wondering if there is a similar way to describe the modulo operation ($x \mod y$) in spoken words.

Comment: $x \operatorname{mod} y$ remainder of $x$ divided by $y$

Comment: It's usually read as "$x$ modulo $y$".  If you don't like that, you could say "the remainder of $x$ on division by $y$".

Comment: The "active" analog of what you wrote is "mod (out) $x$ by $y$" (compare "cast out nines"). This is less common than those mentioned above.

Comment: If there were a verb form for the "mod" operator, it would be a keyword in COBOL.

Comment: @Dan COBOL _does_ have a keyword for the mod operator, `REMAINDER`, which is an optional clause for the `DIVIDE` statement.  For example: `DIVIDE A BY B GIVING C REMAINDER D`.  This seems fairly similar to some of the other comments.

Comment: The word *residue* is also sometimes used in place of *remainder*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to be a verb phrase, I'd go with “Find the remainder when x is divided by y”, or some obvious synonym (“Calculate”, “Compute”, “Determine”, etc.) thereof.

You could also try @Bill Dubuque's suggestion of “Mod (out) x by y”, using “mod” as a verb, but verbing weirds language, so this might be harder to understand.

Note that there are [multiple definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo#Variants_of_the_definition) of `mod` depending on the associated integer division operator (truncated, floored, ceiling, Euclidean, or rounded), so if you're writing documentation for `operator%` in a computer math library, you might want to clarify which one you mean.

Comment: "Mod *out* $x$ by $y$" is more common (so much so that it is even [in Wikipedia).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_(mathematics)#Usage) $\ \ $

Comment: True, but even Wikipedia claims that it is an informal term.

Comment: But "factor out" ideals, congruences, equivalence relations, etc. *is* widely used in formal math, so it makes no sense to deem informal its associated *operational* form "mod out". Likely this occurs because some writers denigrate anything to do with computation - here normal form *operations*. In any case, Wikipedia is very far from being authoritative on such matters.